# Return multiple result in data validation list in Excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I want to make a data validation list includes multiple matches of a   criteria

## Table:

> Row___Column A_____    Column B______________Column C______Column D
>   1  _____ Employee_________Place  ___________  Place__________Employee
>   2 ______Yasser__________ New York___________ Washington________??????
>   3_______Ahmed____________Washington
>   4_______Ali_____________Texas
>   5________Hassan ________New Jersey
>   6______ Ibrahim_________ Texas
>   7______ Alian____________New Jersey
>   8______ Yosef_____________ Texas
>   9______ Ziad_____________New York

## More explain:

- cell [c2] (contains Data validation of places)I choose place of living from it like "New York"
- cell [d2] I want to create a data validation in it.

When I choose a place  from cell[ c2] ,cell [d2] should contain a data validation list of employees  living in that place.

## Example:

When cell [C2] contains New York,Cell [D2] should contain a data validation   list of(Yasser,Ziad)

Comment: Which language is this? Provide more context! Also, put your code properly formated - like this, nobody is able to read it and thus can help you.

Comment: I guess it's an excel formula. Please tag accordingly so that people competent can get involved.

Comment: Hi everybody.Is the question clear enough??